# Hash table collision-handling schemes and the load factors

Tags: hashtable, hash-collision

Which of the hash table collision-handling schemes could tolerate a load factor above 1 and which could not?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Open hashing could, and [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) hashing could not.

Comment: In opposite, open addressing could not tolerate.

Comment: @leventov: *"In opposite, open addressing could not tolerate."* shows *you* don't understand the terminology - [closed hashing *is* open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing).

Comment: Surprizing, counterintuitive terminology.

Comment: @leventov: I agree - very confusing!  When known, I prefer to refer to open hashing's chaining or linked lists, and closed hashing in terms of how further buckets are probed - linearly, quadratically, using offsets from a displacement list etc..  Still, Ana hadn't done a lot of research, so I felt it fair to provide an answer with just enough information for her to Google....